# Adding Browser Link to ListView Items

Tags: android

I have a ListView. I want to go to browser when I press to ListView item. How can I do this?

My ListView onclick code

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            private void startActivity(Intent intent)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
            }
        });
```

When I use this code, ListView item not being clickable.

Comment: You can check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743535/android-listview-onclick-open-a-website

Comment: Post Activity/Fragment code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as you need:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: what question, but i think you forgot something there from your side to do

Answer (score 0):

inside your onCreate

`itemView.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

Then make your class implement AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

There will be an override of onItemClick,inside that override you can do something like this

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position) == 0){
        // Launch the webView
        Intent webIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(webIntent);   
    }      
}
```

Above is how i would go around on this. it should be clean way